# HTML5 required attribute not working in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I am creating a login form for my Ember.js application, and would like to take advantage of the 'required' attribute on inputs for easy client-side validation. However, it seems that this validation does not work when I add an Ember action to the submit button.

For example:

```
<form class="form" role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
      </label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <button {{action 'login'}} class="btn btn-success btn-block">Sign in</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

The moment I remove `{{action 'login'}}` the validation works, otherwise it does not.

How can I get around this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding the action to the button will circumvent the form submit procedure, you'll want to add it to the form submit, and it will only be hit once the form attempts to submit.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" {{action "login" on="submit"}}>
  ...
</form>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tomolevi/1/edit